# Effect of Windows environment variables (especially OMP_NUM_THREADS)

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Does setting OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 in the global environment variables (via Control Panel -> Sytem -> Environment variables) affect only programs run from the command prompt or all programs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say it so: the setting of OpenMP variables like `OMP_NUM_THREADS` affect only **programs** **using** [**OpenMP**](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/).

Since the OpenMP doesn't deal with the GUI so the answer is: it affects console only!

Comment: I think the intent of @Dunkit is to find out whether the variable affects console (text-based) and Windows subsystem applications using OpenMP in the same way